# Match 3+ Column in Reference Data

Tags: excel

[image]This question already has an answer here:

I want to match the Provider ID to Address ID to Prac_ID and get unique APP-ID. Column J K L M is like reference data information. The output should be like written Below in column D.

I used VLOOKUP and SUMIFS function to match these columns but these functions don't work for 3+ columns matching. If any ideas to get output like it is written will be accepted.

Thanks!

VLOOKUP
SUMIFS

## N/A

Comment: Use an INDEX/MATCH array

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a helper column to concatenate the other three columns.

EXAMPLE:

```
=A1&B1&C1
```

AND:

```
=J1&K1&L1
```

Then match on those columns.

Use a tables to automatically copy the equation down to all rows, including new ones. 
Click in to the dataset and press "CTRL+T" to make a table. Do this for both data blocks and ensure that your helper column is included in the tables.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a database. Then you can write proper queries. People graduating from Excel usually use Access as their first database. You will want to study database theory before making the plunge. Your data needs to be structured properly.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I have 20K+ rows in Access and using SQL queries to make columns inner join. But that takes time and I was looking faster way. Match/INDEX works perfectly. :)

Comment: Glad you got is sorted. Can you answer your own question, explain what you did and give an example. Then mark your answer as correct with the green check mark. That will close out this question and help others who follow in your footsteps.